# How can keep maximum of the log-likelihood for LCA model?

Tags: r, model, cluster-analysis

I want to find a better log-likelihood for my LCA model, but I am too sure whether the log-likelihood is as small as possible, or as repeated as possible?
The Question is come from poLCA paper (http://www.sscnet.ucla.edu/polisci/faculty/lewis/pdf/poLCA-JSS-final.pdf  p14. table1)
[image]

I am copy it code trying test

```
## Example data
library(poLCA)
data(gss82)
f <- cbind(PURPOSE,ACCURACY,UNDERSTA,COOPERAT)~1

mlmat <- matrix(NA,nrow=500,ncol=4)

## Do repreat 500 times LCA for best llik
for (i in 1:500) {
  gss.lc <- poLCA(f,gss82,nclass=3,maxiter=3000,tol=1e-7)
  mlmat[i,1] <- gss.lc$llik
  o <- order(gss.lc$probs$UNDERSTA[,1],decreasing=T)
  mlmat[i,-1] <- gss.lc$P[o]
 }
```

Also, I want to know how I can store different maxima of the log-likelihood in my data, like lc_llik_2754.5, lc_llik_27556, lc_llik_2755.7 ...etc.

Thank you!